# Scala : Type Mismatch

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala. Here is my code Snippet

```
  var test_Id:Int = 0
  def getTestID():Int = {
  synchronized {
  return test_Id = test_Id+1
    }
```

This give me a compilation error

```
type mismatch;  found   : Unit  required: Int   HelloWorld.scala
```

I'm defining test_Id as Int. But when i try to return that, it is not identified as Int. How should I return this as Int

Comment: Note the absence of `return` in Lee's reply. In Scala, `return` is used only in unusual circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

Assignment has type `Unit` so you need to separate the update from the read:

```
def getTestID() : Int = {
  synchronized {
      test_Id = test_Id+1
      test_Id
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scala every statement is expression that yields a value. Whatever expression is evaluated at last line in method would be returned. Assignment operation is evaluated as type Unit.
So you need to separate assignment expression from return value expression.

```
  var test_Id:Int = 0
  def getTestID():Int = {
  synchronized {
      test_Id = test_Id+1
      test_Id // return keyword is optional.
  }
```